# How to resolve "hidapi" problems when installing "spl-token-cli" on Ubuntu

Tags: spl-token-cli

How do we resolve `` "failed to run custom build command for `hidapi v1.4.1`" `` when attempting `"cargo install spl-token-cli"` on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Across the different answers that I found, this worked for me and a lot of people who encountered this:

`rustup component add rustfmt`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt install build-essential`

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libudev-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev pkg-config zlib1g-dev llvm clang cmake make libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler`

Then try it again:

`cargo install spl-token-cli`